# Mongoose, Manage Multidimension Array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, multidimensional-array

Is it possible to save this kind of multidimensional array in mongodb?
I want it to be something this kind of hierarchy

Country
City
Town
House

```
countries =[
            [ //Country_1

                [ //City_1

                        [ //town_1
                            [/*house_1*/],
                        ],

                        [//town_2
                            [/*house_1*/],
                        ], 

                ]

            ], //end of Country_1

            [ //Country_2

                [ //City_1 ]

            ], //end of Country_2
        
        ];
```

and update it for some times?

like for example i like to add a new first_layer_3

or

Be able to update and add to Country_1 > City_1 > Town_1 > Add a House

I am open for other way to work this out, pls feel free to suggest and comment things.. THANKS ALOT IN ADVANCE.

Comment: It's technically possible, but it would be hard to maintain. Using nesting with dynamic depth is generally considered as anti-pattern as it introduce unnecessary difficulties to querying the collection.

Comment: @ray so what could be the best way to save this data in mongo?

Comment: There is no silver bullet when it comes to data modelling. Check out [the data modelling section in official document](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/) for some common patterns.